# Harry Potter and Chamber of Secrets (ch 4)

Tags: phrase-meaning

Arthur and Lucius have a bit of a row in the middle of Flourish and Blotts

> "Clearly,” said Mr. Malfoy, his pale eyes straying to Mr. and Mrs. Granger, who were watching apprehensively.
> “The company you keep Weasley....and I thought your family could sink no lower"

> There was a thud of metal as Ginny's cauldron went flying; Mr. Weasley had thrown himself at Mr. Malfoy, knocking him backward
> into a bookshelf. Dozens of heavy spellbooks came thundering down on all their heads.

Why was Ginny's cauldron flying?

Comment: It is impossible to know why the cauldron was flying unless we have more context -- at least a sentence or two before.

Comment: Presumably because someone crashed into it when Mr. Weasley threw himself at Mr Malfoy.  That's why it says "Ginny's cauldron went flying; Mr. Weasley **had** thrown himself", meaning that Mr. Weasley *had already* thrown himself before the cauldron went flying.  But I am not really sure this is an English language question.